# DC analysis of a circuit with direct coupled BJTs

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc

I am teaching myself electronics using a textbook, and I was trying to solve this circuit. I am asked to find \$V_O\$ for V1 voltages of 2 V and 3 V.
The book answers give respectively 9 V and 8.3 V for \$V_O\$

I am unable to reach the same result.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffUGvC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My assumption is that \$\beta_{cc}\$ is large for Q2, so \$I_{B2}\$ is negligible in comparison to \$I_{C1}\$, therefore all of \$I_{C1}\$ flows through \$R_1\$, I can solve quite easily with this assumption, but I'm not getting the expected results.

Can someone help me "unstick" myself?

Comment: I have updated the labels. I double-checked he numbers, this is how they are stated in the exercise.

Comment: Well, 9 V isn't too far off, as would be 3.8 V: *finger rot*?

Comment: Checked again, and the solution states 9V and 8,3V. But maybe it's a typo in the book? not the first one I find. So you confirm that my approach is correct?

Comment: `my approach is correct?` I think the wording unfortunate: literally all current into Q1's collector flows though R1, it's just that a negligible part of the current through the latter flows into Q2. Then, I need a similar assumption for Q1's β.

Comment: The two transistors act as *voltage followers*, the current gain is then less influential than Vbe voltage. Consider current in R3 is almost equivalent to that in R1, and you'll see how much the 16V drop on R1. At that point, the voltage output on R2 will just happen to be that voltage subtracted by Q2 Vbe...

Comment: For V1=2V a rough calculation (based on Vbe=0.7V for both transistors) gives Vo=8.8V.

Comment: We seem to be reaching the same conclusions. I think there is a typo in the book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a ground symbol to your schematic, you can simulate it, and get a very accurate answer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjePdH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It says for \$V_1=3V\$, \$V_{OUT}=4.0V\$, and I believe it, so I'm going with "typo".

For rigor, here's my own working:

Firstly, I assume β is high, so \$I_C=I_E\$ and \$I_B=0\$, for both transistors. Then I assume \$V_{BE}=0.7V\$, for a forward biased base-emitter junction.

E1 will be 0.7V lower than V1:

$$ V_{E1} = V_1 - V_{BE} = +3.0V - 0.7V = +2.3V $$

Current through R3 (\$I_{E1}\$) is:

$$ I_{E1} = \frac{V_{E1}}{R_3} = \frac{2.3}{200} = 11.5mA $$

Collector current \$I_{C1}\$ is the same as \$I_{E1}\$, so the voltage \$V_{R1}\$ across R1 is:

$$ V_{R1} = I_{E1} \times R_1 = 11.5mA \times 1k\Omega = 11.5V $$

Potential \$V_{B2}\$ at Q2's base is:

$$ V_{B2} = V_2 - V_{R1} = 16V - 11.5V = 4.5V $$

Potential \$V_{OUT}\$ is 0.7V lower:

$$ V_{OUT} = V_{B2} - V_{BE} = 4.5V - 0.7V = 3.8V $$

Not exact (because we made some assumptions and approximations; probably should have gone with \$V_{BE}=0.6V\$), but very different from what your book says. To be fair it's easy to type 8.3 when you meant 3.8.

Comment: @Velvel Wow, quick catch! Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Velvel How did you spot that within ten seconds of me submitting it? Are you a wizard?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty when it comes to analog design, so I followed this question for a refresher. Thus I got notified shortly after you've posted your answer. It's a good answer, therefore I upvoted, but thought I should point out that minor typo. The reason I found it relatively quickly is because I tried to understand the formulas and cross verified the respective values. Some people call me nit-picky ;)

Comment: @Velvel Pendantry is the Mother of precision, I applaud your nit-pickyness

Answer (score 2):

Ok, You have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft5hVH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First, we need to assume that all transistors are working in the active region.

Now we can write KVL's equations for the two loops that I have shown on the diagram:

Loop one:
$$V_{IN} = V_{BE1} + V_{RE1} = V_{BE} + I_{E1}*R_{E1}$$

And from this loop we can solve for the \$Q_1\$ emitter current:

$$I_{E1} = \frac{V_{IN} - V_{BE1}}{R_{E1}}$$

The \$Q_1\$ collector current will be equal to

$$I_{C1} = I_{E1} * \frac{\beta_1}{\beta_1 + 1}$$

Btu we usually assumed that \$I_E \approx I_C\$ because the typical \$\beta\$ for small signal transitor is largeer then \$100\$

And the KVL for the second loop:

$$V_{CC} = V_{RC1} + V_{BE2} + V_O = (I_{C1} + I_{B2})*R_{C1} + V_{BE2} + I_{E2}*R_{E2}$$

Additionally, from "transistor action" we know that:

\$I_E = I_B+I_C = I_B + \beta *I_B = (\beta + 1)I_B\$

OR

\$I_B = \frac{I_E}{\beta +1}\$

We can now plug this into the second equation.

$$V_{CC} = (I_{C1} + \frac{I_{E2}}{\beta_2 +1})*R_{C1} + V_{BE2} + I_{E2}*R_{E2}$$

$$ V_{CC} = I_{E2}\left( \frac{R_{C1}}{\beta_2 +1} + R_{E2}\right) + I_{C1}*R_{C2} + V_{BE2} $$

And we can solve for \$I_{E2}\$

$$I_{E2} = \frac{V_{CC} - V_{BE2} -  I_{C1}*R_{C2}}{\frac{R_{C1}}{\beta_2 +1} + R_{E2}}$$

And the voltage across \$R_{E2}\$ is equal to:

$$V_O = I_{E2}*R_{E2}$$

But we can try to use a simplified approach. If we ignore the base currents.
We see that the voltage drop acorss \$R_{C1}\$ is equal to:

$$ V_{RC1} =  \frac{V_{IN} - V_{BE1}}{R_{E1}} * R_{C1} = \left(V_{IN} - V_{BE1}\right)\frac{R_{C1}}{R_{E1}}$$

Thus, the output votlage will be equal to:

$$V_O = V_{CC} - V_{RC1} - V_{BE2} =$$

$$= V_{CC} - \left(V_{IN} - V_{BE1}\right)\frac{R_{C1}}{R_{E1}} - V_{BE2}$$

So, for \$V_{IN} = 2V\$ we have \$V_O = 16V - (2V - 0.7V)*5 - 0.7V = 8.8V\$

And for \$V_{IN} = 3V\$ we have \$V_O = 16V - (3V - 0.7V)*5 - 0.7V = 3.8V\$

Comment: I was taught to do as you have, use arrows for potential differences, that point to the higher potential. Is there any particular reason you do this too? I ask because it has twice been suggested to me that it's not good practice. I disagree, but what's your feeling about it?

Comment: @SimonFitch I was also taught to use it because I was taught to treat the voltage as an "electrical height". And I find it very useful myself. But I can understand why some people don't like it. Especially when different countries use different conventions for arrows. For example, in some countries, the tip of an arrow is pointed toward the lower potential. And some people is using it for current.

Comment: @SimonFitch: To me, the arrow screams "current".  For voltage the convention is a +/- pair.

Comment: One argument against the shown arrow directions:  The direction of the red arrow Vbe is opposite to the arrow of the npn symbol - and the same would apply to the pn-diode. I prefer the other alternative (point to the lower potential). Moreofter, the latter is in accordance with the current (conventional direction) through a resistor.

Comment: For me, the arrows have always pointed in the direction of current and indicated a voltage drop (if V/I was positive). However, if there is ambiguity, I would just add the +/- markers next to the arrow to remove that in the documentation.